# Python panda search for value in a df from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I’ve got two data frames :-

Df1

```
Time   V1    V2
02:00  D3F3  0041
02:01  DD34  0040
```

Df2

```
 FileName  V1    V2
   1111.txt  D3F3  0041
   2222.txt  0000  0040
```

Basically I want to compare the v1 v2 columns and if they match print the row time from df1 and the row from df2 filename. So far all i can find is the

> isin()

, which simply gives you a boolean output.

So the output would be :

> 1111.txt 02:00

I started using dataframes because i though i could query the two df's on the V1 / V2 values but I can't see a way. Any pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge` on the dataframe columns that you want to have the same values. You can then drop the rows with NaN values, as those will not have matching values. From there, you can print the merged dataframes values however you see fit.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['8a', '10p'], 'V1': [1, 2], 'V2': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fn': ['8.txt', '10.txt'], 'V1': [3, 2], 'V2': [3, 4]})

df1.merge(df2, on=['V1', 'V2'], how='outer').dropna()
```

=== Output: ===

```
  Time  V1  V2      fn
1  10p   2   4  10.txt
```

Comment: So I tried the suggestion ' code' new.merge(new, on=['V'], how='outer').dropna() 'code'   and get this. I changed the V1/V2 column to V and merged the two strings to simply it and also changed case both to lower and removed any whitespace.                                                                                      
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time, V, File]
Index: []

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive solution is:
1) iterate the V1 column in DF1;
2) for each item in this column, check if this item exists in the V1 column of DF2;
3) if the item exists in DF2's V1, then find the index of that item in the DF2 and then you would be able to find the file name.

Comment: Iterating through rows in a dataframe is 100X slower than the merge/join method. Pandas is designed to work with matrix-level transforms, not iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `pd.concat`.

On this case it would be like:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.reindex(df1.index)], axis=1)
```

It will create a new dataframe with all the values, but in case there are some values that doesn't match in both dataframes, it'll return `NaN`. If you doesn't want this to happen you must use this:

```
pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join='inner')
```

If you wanna learn a bit more, use pydata: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge option with inner join

```
    df2.merge(df1,how="inner",on=["V1","V2"])[["FileName","Time"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

While I think Eric's solution is more pythonic, if your only aim is to print the rows on which df1 and df2 have v1 and v2 values the same, provided the two dataframes are of the same length, you can do the following:

```
for row in range(len(df1)):
    if (df1.iloc[row,1:] == df2.iloc[row,1:]).all() == True: 
        print(df1.iloc[row], df2.iloc[row])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')

obj = client.get_object(Bucket='', Key='')
data = obj['Body'].read()
df1 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data), sheet_name='0')
df2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data), sheet_name='1')

head = df2.columns[0]
print(head)

data = df1.iloc[[8],[0]].values[0]
print(data)

print(df2)
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2.drop(labels=0, axis=0)
df2['Head'] = head
df2['ID'] = pd.Series([data,data])

print(df2)
df2.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```